# A better way to simulate a qml button click in c++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

My main objective is to write a test case that can simulate a qml button click from C++. The code snippet below accomplishes this but it requires a `qobject_cast()` from qobject to qwindow. Is there an option to implement a mouse click that takes a qobject? Is this the correct way to implement the button click or is there a better way?

`main.qml` file

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button {
        id: button
        objectName: "button"
        x: 54
        y: 118
        text: qsTr("Button")
        checkable: true
        onClicked: {
            button.text = qsTr("Clicked")
        }
    }
}
```

`myClass.h` file

```
...
public:
    void ClickItem(QObject*);

private slots:
    void test_case1();

private:
    QWindow *m_window; 
...
```

`myClass.cpp` file

```
void myClass::ClickItem(QObject* pItem)
{
    int x = pItem->property("x").toInt();
    int y = pItem->property("y").toInt();

    QPoint location(x,  y);
    QTest::mouseClick(m_window, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier, location);
}

void myClass::test_case1()
{
    QObject *engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:../app/Display.qml")));
    object = component.create();

    m_window = qobject_case<QWindow *>(object);

    QObject *item = object->findChild<QObject*>("button");
    if (item) {
        myClass::ClickItem(item);
        QVariant value = item->property("text");
        QCOMPARE(value.toString(), QString("Clicked"));
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Did not work";
    }
}
```

Comment: Curious - do you really want to simulate clicking a mouse button, or do you want to test the code that gets invoked when a user normally clicks that button?

Comment: There are frameworks that are especially made for testing UIs by simulating user interaction. Use one of those.

Comment: Are you referring to frameworks such as qmltestcase with qt quick test?

Comment: What we do on my product team. Each QML element is decorated with accessibility properties. Then we use accessibility and system APIs on Windows and Mac to locate the control, position the mouse, and simulate a click.  Other frameworks do similar stuff and/or insert themselves as a debugger and do similar commanding. One framework in particular that I know of that that works specifically for Qt is this: https://www.froglogic.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
QObject* obj = view.findChild<QObject*>("button");

QEvent evtPress(QEvent::MouseButtonPress);
QEvent evtRelease(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease);

obj->event(&evtPress);
obj->event(&evtRelease);
```