# Can the javascript trigger clicks on components in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

Let's suppose i have a `Button`, `MouseArea`or something like that in qml. And instead of manually instead of a user doing a click on those components i want it to be done with a `script`.

Is this possible to do in `qml`?

for example lets suppose i have a `MouseArea`like this:

```
    MouseArea {
        id:panelAreaClick
        anchors.fill: parent
        cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
        onClicked: function(){
            isSelected = !isSelected
        }
    }
```

But sometimes i want a script do trigger the click on the mousearea too:

```
function click(){
    panelAreaClick.click()
}
```

This obviously is not working, but is there a way?

Comment: if it does not need to be from qml-part of your code, this should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54068360/a-better-way-to-simulate-a-qml-button-click-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually possible if you manually trigger the signal `clicked`:

```
function click() {
    panelAreaClick.clicked(null) // you need to pass 1 argument since clicked needs a MouseAvent argument
}
```

But it is very bad design in my opinion. Also be aware that the `mouse` parameter will be `null` in the `onClicked` signal handler.

You can do the opposite:

```
// in MouseArea:
onClicked: toggleSelection()
```

with:

```
// function callable from anywhere
function toggleSelection() {
    panelAreaClick.isSelected = !panelAreaClick.isSelected
}
```